# Can't seem to click on this drop down properly using selenium, I've tried multiple techniques and even tried executing JS code

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Everything works as intended, besides the last part in the try block. Granted there is a lot of comments in this try block of past attempts, which have all failed. In the first screenshot [screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm1jE.png) it shows what it should look like if I manually click the arrow for the drop down. And in the second screenshot it shows what the code currently does [screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzYHy.png). It seems like the website that I click on only appears correctly if I follow the procedure in the code (login to class registation, click submit, and then click Get Registed on another page that sends me to the one I'm currently working on). I understand that it would be pretty hard to help me due to the fact that you can only login in with my credentials, unless you are a student at OSU.

I tried multiple ways of accessing the correct HTML Id's, but it still doesn't seem to work. I believe it's because when I manually click the drop down it activates a JS script that allows the user to click on the webpage? Not entirely sure. I believe this is the relevant HTML

```
<div ng-cloak="" id="shortcut_module_added" dir="auto">
    <xe-popup-modal xe-id="keyboardShortcutLabel" show="modalShown" focusbackelement="tools" pageheader="Keyboard shortcuts">
        <popup-content>
            <div>
                <div ng-repeat="bannershortcut in shortcutObj" class="banner_aria-shortcut_{{$index}}" ng-class="banner_shortcut_{{$id}} ? 'shortcut-container-collapse' : 'shortcut-container-expanded'">
                    <span class="content-heading-shortcut" tabindex="0" ng-keydown="showDescription($event)" data-ng-bind="bannershortcut.sectionHeading" ng-click="showDescription($event)"></span>
                    <span class="shortcutAccordion" ng-keydown="showDescription($event)" ng-click="showDescription($event)" ng-class="!banner_shortcut_{{$id}} ? 'up' : 'down'"></span>
                    <div class="banner-shortcut banner_shortcut_{{$index}}" id="banner_shortcut_{{$id}}" ng-show="!banner_shortcut_{{$id}}">
                        <div class="shortcut-row" ng-repeat="hotkey in bannershortcut.shortcutList">
                            <div class="shortcut-description" aria-label="{{hotkey.description}}" data-ng-bind="hotkey.description"></div>
                            <div class="column-container">
                                <span ng-repeat-start="item in hotkey.combo" class="chicklet" data-ng-bind="item"></span><div class="delimiter-shortcut" ng-repeat-end="" ng-if="!$last">&nbsp;</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </popup-content>
    </xe-popup-modal>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/StudentRegistrationSsb/assets/modules/bannerWeb-mf.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
    var mepcodeChanged='';
    if(null !== mepcodeChanged && undefined !== mepcodeChanged && mepcodeChanged == "true"){
        $(document).bind('notification-use-ready', function (e) {
            mepcodeNotificationAddition(window.mepCode)
        });
    }
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="/StudentRegistrationSsb/assets/modules/personaChange-mf.js"></script>


<main id="content" role="main" class="ui-layout-container" style="top: 99px; overflow: hidden; margin-bottom: 0px;">
    <div class="custom-css-class">
        <div id="title-panel" class="aurora-theme"><h1>Select a Term</h1></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-layout-north inner-north ui-layout-pane ui-layout-pane-north" id="inner-north" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; inset: 0px 0px auto; width: auto; z-index: 0; height: 1px; display: block; visibility: visible;"></div>

    <div class="ui-layout-center inner-center overflow-pane ui-layout-pane ui-layout-pane-center" id="inner-center" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; inset: 1px 0px 0px; height: 810px; width: 779px; z-index: 0; display: block; visibility: visible;">
        <div class="body-wrapper">
            <div class="body-content">
                <div class="overlay" style="display: none;"></div>
                <div id="term-date-selection" tabindex="0" class="ui-widget-content  vertical-form labels-above">
                    <div id="term-buttons">
                        <fieldset role="form">
                            <legend>Select a Term</legend>
                            <div id="term-select" role="search">
                                
                            </div>

                            <div id="term-window">
                                <div id="term-search-combobox">
                                    <label class="form-row" for="txt_term">
                                        
                                            Terms Open for Registration
                                        
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="select2-container term-combo2" id="s2id_txt_term" title="Select a term..." aria-required="true"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice select2-default" tabindex="-1">   <span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-1">Select a term...</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>   <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></a><label for="s2id_autogen1" class="select2-offscreen">
                                        
                                            Terms Open for Registration
                                        
                                    </label><input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-describedby="screen-reader-label-1" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-1" id="s2id_autogen1" aria-controls="select2-chosen-1" tabindex="0"><div class="select2-drop select2-display-none select2-with-searchbox">   <div class="select2-search">       <label for="s2id_autogen1_search" class="select2-offscreen">
                                        
                                            Terms Open for Registration
                                        
                                    </label>       <input type="text" sanitize="true" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="select2-results-1" id="s2id_autogen1_search" placeholder="" tabindex="0">   </div>   <ul class="select2-results" role="listbox" id="select2-results-1">   </ul></div></div><input type="hidden" id="txt_term" name="txt_term" class="term-combo2" data-init-text="" value="" data-endpoint="/StudentRegistrationSsb/ssb/classRegistration/getTerms" data-save-endpoint="/StudentRegistrationSsb/ssb/term/saveTerm?mode=registration" data-allowmultiple="false" data-mode="registration" placeholder="Select a term..." tabindex="-1" title="
                                        
                                            Terms Open for Registration
                                        
                                    " style="display: none;">
                                    <br>
                                    
                                        
                                        <div id="div_alt_pin" class="visuallyhidden disabled" disabled="disabled"><br><label class="form-row" for="input_alt_pin">Alternate PIN<span class="required-mark" style="display: none;">*</span></label><input id="input_alt_pin" type="password" class="visuallyhidden disabled" disabled="disabled"><br>
                                        </div>
                                    

                                    <div id="searchAdvisee" style="display: none;">

                                        
                                    </div>
                                    

                                </div>

                                <div id="search-dates" style="display: none;">
                                    <label id="startDate-label" class="datePicker form-row" for="startDatepicker">Start Date</label>

                                    <div class="search-date"><input type="text" id="startDatepicker" name="startDatepicker" aria-label="Start Date format Month/Day/Year Date format is M M / d d / y y y y" title="Press F9 to open/close the calendar" class="hasMultiCalendarPicker" placeholder="MM/dd/yyyy"><span class="calendar-icon calendar-img"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <label id="endDate-label" class="datePicker form-row" for="endDatepicker">End Date</label>

                                    <div class="search-date"><input type="text" id="endDatepicker" name="endDatepicker" aria-label="End Date format Month/Day/Year Date format is M M / d d / y y y y" title="Press F9 to open/close the calendar" class="hasMultiCalendarPicker" placeholder="MM/dd/yyyy"><span class="calendar-icon calendar-img"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>

                    </div>

                    <div id="termStudentEligibilityErrors" style="display: none;"></div>
                    <div class="form-end-controls">
                        <button id="term-go" type="button" data-endpoint="/StudentRegistrationSsb/ssb/term/search?mode=registration" class="form-button">Continue</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="" class="ui-layout-resizer ui-layout-resizer-north ui-layout-resizer-open ui-layout-resizer-north-open" style="position: absolute; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-size: 1px; text-align: left; overflow: hidden; z-index: 2; top: 1px; cursor: default; display: none;"></div></main>

<div id="popups-container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/StudentRegistrationSsb/assets/modules/termView-mf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/StudentRegistrationSsb/assets/modules/registrationView-mf.js"></script>






<script type="text/javascript">
        var isExperienceIntegrated = ('false'.length != 0) ? (Boolean('false') && 'false' !== 'false') : false;
        if ((isExperienceIntegrated==true) && !(window.self !== window.top))
        {
            var url = '/StudentRegistrationSsb/error/standaloneApplication';
            window.location.replace(url);
        }
    </script><script>
        var extensibilityInfo = {
  "application": "StudentRegistrationSsb",
  "page": "term",
  "url": "/StudentRegistrationSsb/",
  "pluginUrl": "/StudentRegistrationSsb/plugins/web-app-extensibility-10.1/static/html/",
  "admin": false,
  "extensions": {},
  "resources": null
}
        window.mepCode='';
    </script><script>

        var transactionTimeoutMeta    = $( "meta[name=transactionTimeout]" ),
            transactionTimeoutSeconds = ( transactionTimeoutMeta.length == 1 ? parseInt( transactionTimeoutMeta.attr( "content" ) ) : 30 ),
            transactionTimeoutPadding = 10 * 1000,
            transactionTimeoutMilli   = ( transactionTimeoutSeconds * 1000 ) + transactionTimeoutPadding;

        $.ajaxSetup( { timeout: transactionTimeoutMilli } );

    </script><script>
    $(window).load(function() {
           $( "#splash" ).remove();
         });


     yepnope({
     test : window.JSON,
     nope : '/StudentRegistrationSsb/assets/json2.js'
      });

      $(window).load(function() {
          _.defer( function() {
              $( "#splash" ).remove();
          });
      });
```

[screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGBvZ.png)

I am also new to webscraping, so apologizes if this is hard to understand/read.

This is my code, again apologizes it is very messy atm:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import selenium.webdriver.support.wait as wait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException, NoSuchWindowException, TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
import threading
import os
#import env file .env
from dotenv import load_dotenv
chrome_options = Options()


driver = webdriver.Edge(chrome_options)
url="https://classes.oregonstate.edu/?keyword=CS261&srcdb=202402"
driver.get(url)
orginal_window=driver.current_window_handle
load_dotenv()
#username=os.getenv("USERNAME")
#password=os.getenv("PASSWORD")

username='username'
password='password'
def get_user_input():
    global set_up_classes
    set_up_classes= input("Have you set up classes already?")

#/html[1]/body[1]/header[1]/div[2]/a[1]
try:
    
    the_url=driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html[1]/body[1]/header[1]/div[2]/a[1]")
    print(the_url.get_attribute("href"))
    the_url.click()
    if len(driver.window_handles) > 1:
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        print(driver.current_url)
        login_url=driver.current_url
        
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "username")))
        username_driver=driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="username").send_keys(username)
        time.sleep(3)

        password_selector="#password"
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, password_selector)))

        password_driver=driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=password_selector)

        for char in password:
            password_driver.send_keys(char)
            time.sleep(0.2)
    #https://api-46217189.duosecurity.com/frame/v4/auth/prompt?sid=frameless-b19a6056-caa0-4b20-8466-aeb92dc48b4d
    #https://api-46217189.duosecurity.com/frame/v4/auth/prompt?sid=frameless-7d2e5402-6038-4783-af32-ca317ea6057f   
        button_driver=driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="body > main > form > div:nth-child(4) > button").click()
        #button_driver.click()
        #driver.switch_to.window(orginal_window)
        #print(driver.current_url)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#auth-view-wrapper > div:nth-child(2) > div.row.display-flex.align-flex-justify-content-center.verification-code")))
        code=driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="#auth-view-wrapper > div:nth-child(2) > div.row.display-flex.align-flex-justify-content-center.verification-code").text
        DUO= driver.current_url
        print("Please type in DUO CODE:"+code)
        windows=driver.window_handles
        if len(windows) > 1:
            driver.switch_to.window(windows[1])
        else:
            print("No DUO window found")
        #Sleep until driver.current_window_handle is not DUO
        time.sleep(15)
        #try:

        #/html/body
        ##dont-trust-browser-button
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#dont-trust-browser-button")))
        trust_button = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="#dont-trust-browser-button")
        print("attempting to click")
        trust_button.click()
        print("clicked")
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.staleness_of(trust_button))
        time.sleep(10)
        print("Clicked on 'Yes, this is my device' button.")
        # Wait for any overlay to disappear (check if 'lfjs_modaldiv' is present and wait until it's not visible)
        #WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until_not(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "lfjs_modaldiv")))
        #print("Overlay has disappeared.")
        #print("Clicked on 'Yes, this is my device' button.")
        #driver.switch_to.default_content()
        """ except TimeoutException:
            print("The 'Yes, this is my device' button was not clickable after 10 seconds.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An exception occurred while trying to click the button: {e}") """
        
        driver.switch_to.window(orginal_window)
        ##primary-cart-button
        #time.sleep(10)
        #wait until input is typed
        print("Before switching to default" +str(driver.current_url))
        #time.sleep(3)
        
        #Clicks on primary cart button
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/button[1]")))
        enroll = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html[1]/body[1]/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/button[1]")
        enroll.click()
        
        #click on submit schedule button
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/main[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/button[2]")))
        submit_schedule = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html[1]/body[1]/main[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/button[2]")
        original_window = driver.current_window_handle

        # Click to open the 2nd tab
        submit_schedule.click()

        # Wait for the 2nd tab and switch to it
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
        windows_handles = driver.window_handles
        second_tab = [window for window in windows_handles if window != original_window][0]
        driver.switch_to.window(second_tab)
        print("Switched to second tab")

        # Click to open the 3rd tab
        #abs xpath is: /html[1]/body[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/span[1]/div[1]/a[1]/button[1]/div[1]/div[1]
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/span[1]/div[1]/a[1]/button[1]/div[1]/div[1]")))
        get_registered = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html[1]/body[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/span[1]/div[1]/a[1]/button[1]/div[1]/div[1]")
        get_registered.click()    
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(3))
        windows_handles = driver.window_handles
        third_tab = [window for window in windows_handles if window not in [original_window, second_tab]][0]
        driver.switch_to.window(third_tab)
        print("Switched to third tab")


        try:
            #need to fix the dropdown menu part that still isn't working.
            '''WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#s2id_txt_term > a")))
            select2_box = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="#s2id_txt_term > a")
            select2_box.click()
            print("clicked")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".select2-input")))
            select2_input=driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=".select2-input")
            select2_input.send_keys("Winter 2024")
            #term-go'''

            '''WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#s2id_txt_term > a > span.select2-arrow")))
            select2_box = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="#s2id_txt_term > a > span.select2-arrow")
            select2_box.click()
            print("clicked")
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".select2-input")))
            select2_input=driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=".select2-input")
            select2_input.send_keys("Winter 2024")
            print("sent keys")'''

            # Click the dropdown to open it
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".select2-container")))
            select2_dropdown = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=".select2-container")
            select2_dropdown.click()
            print("clicked")

            # Wait for the search box within the dropdown to be visible
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#select2-result-label-3")))
            select2_search_box = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="#select2-result-label-3")
            select2_search_box.click()
            print("clicked")

            # Wait for the desired option to be clickable
            '''WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[contains(text(), 'Winter 2024')]")))
            select2_option = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//li[contains(text(), 'Winter 2024')]")
            select2_option.click()
            print("clicked")'''
            time.sleep(50)
            #WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#term-go")))
            #select4_box = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="#term-go")
            #select4_box.click()
            #select2_box.send_keys("Winter 2024")
            # Send keys to the search box within the Select2 dropdown
            
           
            '''
           
            script =  """
                var select2Container = $('#select2-container-id'); // Use the actual ID or class of the Select2 container
                select2Container.select2('open');

                // Wait for the dropdown to open and for the search box to become visible
                setTimeout(function() {
                var searchBox = $('input.select2-search__field');
                searchBox.val('Winter 2024').trigger('input');

                // Wait for the results to be filtered and become visible
                setTimeout(function() {
                    var results = $('.select2-results__option:contains("Winter 2024")');
                    if (results.length) {
                    results.trigger('mouseup'); // or .trigger('click');
                    }
                }, 500); // Increase this time if necessary
                }, 500); // Increase this time if necessary
                """
            driver.execute_script(script)
        '''
        except TimeoutException as e:
            print("Element not found within the time frame.")
            # Optionally, take a screenshot to help with debugging
            driver.save_screenshot('debug_screenshot.png')

      
        

        #/html[1]/body[1]/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/button[1]
        time.sleep(20)
except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException, NoSuchWindowException) as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
finally:
    driver.quit()
```